# How can I fix the error while adding to the database in python code?

Tags: python, database, tkinter

I have database named "adressbook" and with codes table is created in the database, there is no problem in this part but I get an error while adding data message box shows "An error occurred while adding to the database.". I couldn't fix it. How can I fix this situation?

```
try:
  import tkinter as tk
  from tkinter import filedialog
  from tkinter import messagebox
  import sqlite3
  from PIL import Image, ImageTk
  print("Kutuphanler import edildi.")
except:
  !pip install pysqlite3
  !pip install PILLOW
  print("\n\nHucreyi yeniden calistiriniz.")
def openConn(dbName:str):
    # Veritabanina baglanma
    conn = sqlite3.connect(dbName)
    #Veritabaninda  islemi yapabilmek icin cursor tanimlama
    cur = conn.cursor()
    return conn, cur

#Veritabani olusturma
def createTable(dbName:str, tableName:str):
    try:
        conn, cur = openConn(dbName)
        sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE  {}(firstName text, middleName text, surname text, DOB text, address text, city text, country text, zipcode text, imPath text)".format(tableName)
        cur.execute(sqlQuery)
        conn.close()
        return True
    except:
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Hata", "Veritabani olusturulurken hata meydana geldi.")
        return False

#Her bir girdinin uygun formatta gosterilmesi
def strResult(result):
    return "{} {} {}, {} - {}, {}, {}, {}".format(result[0],result[1],result[2],result[3],result[4],result[5],result[6],result[7])


#Tum entry alanlarinin temizlenmesi
def clearAllEntries():
    #Olusturdugunuz tum entry widgetlarin iceriklerini temizleyiniz
    myEntry.delete(0, 'end')
    return True

#Tum Verilerin okunmasi
def printAllRecords(dbName:str, tableName:str):
    try:
        conn, cur = openConn(dbName)
        sqlQuery = "SELECT *, oid FROM {}".format(tableName)
        resultSet = cur.execute(sqlQuery)

        for result in resultSet:
            strResult = strEntry(result)
            tempLabel = tk.Label(formApp, text = strResult)
        return True
    except:
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Hata","Verilerin okunmasi esnasinda hata olustu")
        return False

#Veritabanina entry degerinin eklenmesi
def insertEntry(dbName:str, tableName:str,entryValues:list):
    try:
        conn, cur = openConn(dbName)
        sqlQuery= "INSERT INTO {} VALUES({},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}) ".format(tableName, entryValues[0], entryValues[1], entryValues[2], entryValues[3], entryValues[4], entryValues[5], entryValues[6], entryValues[7], entryValues[8])
        cur.execute(sqlQuery)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        clearAllEntries()
        printAllRecords()
        return True
    except:
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Hata","An error occurred while adding to the database.")
        return False


def openImageFile():
    global img, photo
    imPath = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:\\", title = "Open an image", filetypes = (("PNG file","*.png"), ("JPEG File","*.jpeg"), ("JPG File","*.jpg"), ("All File Types","*.*")) )

    if imPath:
        img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imPath))
        photo.configure(image=img)
```

And button and entry list

```
entry_list=[firstName_entry,middleName_entry,surname_entry,date_entry,address_entry,city_entry,country_entry,zipCode_entry]

    btnSubmit = tk.Button(appWin, text ="Insert Item", command=lambda: insertEntry(dbName=DB_NAME, tableName=TABLE_NAME, entryValues = [entry_list]))
```

I don't understand Is there a fault in the InsertEntry function? Or Is it in the button part?

Answer (score 0):

At the `insertEntry` function you can try to print Exception message so not custom message. You can try

```
try:
...
except Exception as e:
print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error should be on this line:

```py
sqlQuery= "INSERT INTO {} VALUES({},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}) ".format(tableName, entryValues[0], entryValues[1], entryValues[2], entryValues[3], entryValues[4], entryValues[5], entryValues[6], entryValues[7], entryValues[8])
```

If, for example, `entryValues[0]` (according to your table definition, it is the `firstName`) has value `John`, then the final SQL statement will look like:

```
INSERT INTO sometable VALUES(John,...)
```

But the expected SQL statement should be:

```
INSERT INTO sometable VALUES("John",...)
```

Use placeholders in the SQL statement as below:

```
sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO {} VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)".format(tableName)
cur.execute(sqlQuery, (entryValues[0].get(), entryValues[1].get(), entryValues[2].get(),
                       entryValues[3].get(), entryValues[4].get(), entryValues[5].get(),
                       entryValues[6].get(), entryValues[7].get(), entryValues[8].get()))
# or shorter version
# cur.execute(sqlQuery, [e.get() for e in entryValues])
```

Note that `entryValues` are list of `Entry`, so need to use `get()` to get the value.

Also, the following line

```
btnSubmit = tk.Button(appWin, text="Insert Item",
                      command=lambda: insertEntry(dbName=DB_NAME, tableName=TABLE_NAME, 
                                                  entryValues=[entry_list]))
```

should be

```
btnSubmit = tk.Button(appWin, text="Insert Item",
                      command=lambda: insertEntry(dbName=DB_NAME, tableName=TABLE_NAME, 
                                                  entryValues=entry_list)) # without []
```